# I am using boost hash function in C++ to combine 3 doubles into a hash which is facing a collision

Tags: c++

By failing I mean it is giving a repeated value for different group of double. The three doubles are x, y and z of a vertex. I have a list of vertices and using the hash created from the doubles as a key in the map. I was wondering if a more reliable hash combine function for this specific application exists.

```
  template <class T>
    inline void hash_combine(std::size_t& seed, T const& v)
    {
        seed ^= std::hash<T>()(v) + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed << 6) + (seed >> 2);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have a list of vertices and using the hash created from the doubles as a key in the map.

Not the best use of a hash, in the sense of what `std::hash` or `boost::hash` represents.

You're looking for uniqueness. A hash in this sense is not unique.

> I was wondering if a more reliable hash combine function for this specific application exists.

Not unless the hash space has a 1:1 correlation with the space of possible values of z, y and z - which essentially means using the vertex itself as the identifier.

Summary:

If you want a container indexed by unique vertices, you may want to consider a std::unordered_map. You will need to provide an equality operator.

An example:

```
#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp> // see below
#include <tuple>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>

// a simple Vertex class
struct Vertex
{
    double x, y, z;
};

// a useful general-purpose accessor
auto as_tuple(Vertex const& v) -> decltype(auto)
{
    return std::tie(v.x, v.y, v.z);
}

// equality implemented in terms of tuple, for simplicity
bool operator==(Vertex const& l , Vertex const& r)
{
    return as_tuple(l) == as_tuple(r);
}

// hash_value implemented in terms of tuple, for consistency and simplicity
std::size_t hash_value(Vertex const& v)
{
    using boost::hash_value;
    return hash_value(as_tuple(v));
}

// the boring bit - injecting a hash specialisation into the std:: namespace
// but let's derive from boost's hash class, which is much better
// in that it allows easy hashing using free functions
namespace std {
    template<> struct hash<::Vertex> : boost::hash<::Vertex> {};
}

using vertex_map = std::unordered_map<Vertex, std::string>;

int main()
{
    auto m = vertex_map();

    m[{0, 0, 0}] = "Sol";
    m[{1, 3, 5}] = "Mars";
    m[{100.4, 343.2, 92.44}] = "Pluto";
}
```

Note: The numbers above are in Zargian NonLinear Megaunits - you won't find them in any Earthbound textbook on the Solar System.